# Modifying a restored TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have trained a TensorFlow (TF) CNN model on the MNIST dataset and stored the model after training using *tf.train.Saver()*. Now, I'd like to restore this model and add an operation between two layers before retraining it, e.g., adding *tf.stop_gradient()* between the output of the first convolution layer (named 'conv1') and the first pooling layer (named 'pool1'). Is that possible? If so, how could I do it?

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/home/frr/MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

learning_rate = 0.001
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 64
display_step = 20
ImVecDim = 784
NumOfClasses = 10
dropout = 0.8

g = tf.get_default_graph()

with tf.Session() as sess:
   LoadMod = tf.train.import_meta_graph('simple_mnist.ckpt.meta')
   LoadMod.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))

#############################################################################
#     Adding a tf.stop_gradient() operation between 'conv1' and 'pool1'     #
#############################################################################

   x = g.get_tensor_by_name('ImageIn:0')
   y = g.get_tensor_by_name('LabelIn:0')
   keep_prob = g.get_tensor_by_name('KeepProb:0')
   accuracy = g.get_tensor_by_name('NetAccuracy:0')
   optimizer = g.get_operation_by_name('Adam')
   step = 1
   while step * batch_size < training_iters:
       batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

       sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys, keep_prob: dropout})
       if step % display_step == 0:
          acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys, keep_prob: 1.})
          print("Iter " + str(step*batch_size) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(acc))
   step += 1
   print("Optimization Finished!")
   print("Testing Accuracy:",
   sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:256], y: mnist.test.labels[:256], keep_prob: 1.}))
```

Comment: Have you tried directly adding `tf.stop_gradient()` to the original code where the output of `conv1` is defined? Does any error occur?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Richard_wth. I can do what you suggested, but it is not exactly what I need. The restored model has already been trained, so I'd like to restore it and, then, add `tf.stop_gradient()` between `conv1` and `pool1`. The reason I am doing this is that I want to retrain the layers 2-6 on a different dataset.

Comment: I assume you were using `tf.layers.conv2d` or `tf.get_variable` to initialize the weight/bias. How about setting `trainable=False` for the weight/bias of `conv1` in the fine-tuning run? Can the model be restored? Would the weight still get updated?

Comment: `@Richard_wth`, I used neither! I cannot set the option `trainable = False` because the I am retraining a restored model. I think setting `trainable=False` works only if you are training the model from scratch, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Well...the `tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist` code uses `tf.Variable` which you could set `trainable=False`. If somehow you really do not want to modify the original code, how about passing the loss to a new optimizer `new_opt` with `new_opt.minimize(loss, var_list=var_list, ...)` where `var_list` contains the weights/bias you want to update?

Comment: Actually, this is what I did; however, what I want to know is whether modifying a restored model is possible or not.