# Tensorflow 2: modify model from hub (resnet)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

How can I modify the model graph and functions (not just variable values) of Tensorflow 2 models restored from the hub?

(This seems like the same motivation as [Modifying a restored TensorFlow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216183/modifying-a-restored-tensorflow-model) but for Tensorflow 2.)

In particular, for [resnet_v1_101](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_101/classification) (version 4 as of this writing), I have tried `tensorflow_hub.KerasLayer`, `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model`, `tensorflow.saved_model.load`, and `tensorflow_hub.load`.  None of these resulted in an object that has any functions or properties to view the flow graph (let alone modify it).  I presume this is because the model was ported from an earlier Tensorflow or otherwise undecorated when saved, but surely the flow graph and functions must be available for its own internal computation?

Messing with the .pb binary directly would be exsanguinating.

---

UPDATE: I found an alternative approach that should work for for my situation: avoid the hub altogether and use tensorflow.keras.applications.ResNet101 instead.  For models not implemented in keras applications, it would still be nice to have an answer to the original question.

Comment: What error are you facing while loading the model from TF-Hub? Include the logs.

Comment: I haven't seen any errors.